# Questions about set cardinalities (infinite/finite).

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have a couple questions that I undertstood (maybe) intuitively and tried to prove them somehow, I would like if someone can give feedback and tell me if I'm doing it the right way. 
True or false:
1)$ |\{ \frac {1} {2^n} \mid n\in \mathbb{N} \}| = |\mathbb{N}|$ 
.
Intuitively this seems true, and I thought of proving it by introducing the function $f: \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \{ \frac {1} {2^n} \mid n\in \mathbb{N} \}$, $f(n)=\frac {1} {2^n}$. 

2) $K= \{A\in P(\mathbb{N}) \mid A \space is \space finite \} $, Assumption: $K$ is finite.

Intuitively I can see it's infinite, since the power set of natural numbers have infinity elements, but I really don't know how to prove it.

3) $L= \{A\in P(\mathbb{N}) \mid A^c \space is \space finite \}$,
Assumption $L$ is finite. 
I think this is true, since for all $A\in P(\mathbb{N})$, $A^c$ is infinite, so theres no elements in $L$. 

I would really appreciate it if someone can approve my work, and tell me how to formalize the proofs, and point out my mistakes. Thanks in advance

Comment: For $2):$ $\{n\}\in K, \forall n\in \mathbb N.$ So, $K$ can't be finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2. Just give an infinite number of elements of $K$, for example all $\{k\}$ are in  for $k\in \mathbb{N}$.
3. If $A^c$ is the complementary of $A$, then I think the proposition is false, since the $\{n; n\geqslant k\}$ are in $L$ for all $k$.